# Changing the text on a button when a tab is selected in a tabview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to learn objective-c by making a GUI application using Xcode 3.  I'm wondering if it is possible to change the text of a button outside of a tab view depending on which tab in the tabview is selected?  As I said I am trying to learn objective-c so please act as though I know next to nothing in your answer.  I should probably mention that I tried making a NSObject and tried to define an IBAction in a .h and .m file but that didn't seem to work. (I have tried setting some breakpoints in those files none of which were ever reached leading me to think something isn't wired the way think it is.)

Sorry for the long winded explanation.
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out.  What I needed was object delegation, this [page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTabViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), and of course Google to help get the correct syntax for the actual implementation.